# Delphi: Setting timestamp of file wrong by one hour for some files

Tags: datetime, delphi, time, delphi-2010, timestamp-with-timezone

I want to correct the last-access time of some files.
Doing that programmatically fails - by one hour - for some files.
Mysterious, as I do correct the date according to the timezone.

Here is an example, tested for Delphi2010 (that's where I would need code for) and Delphi10.3

```
function GetTempDir : string;
var path : array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
    PathStr : string;
begin
     GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, path);
     PathStr:=path;
     result:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(PathStr);
end;

function UTCDateTimeFromLocalDateTime(const LocalDateTime: TDateTime): TDateTime;
var
  LocalSystemTime: TSystemTime;
  UTCSystemTime: TSystemTime;
  LocalFileTime: TFileTime;
  UTCFileTime: TFileTime;
begin
  DateTimeToSystemTime(LocalDateTime, UTCSystemTime);
  SystemTimeToFileTime(UTCSystemTime, UTCFileTime);

  if LocalFileTimeToFileTime(UTCFileTime, LocalFileTime)
  and FileTimeToSystemTime(LocalFileTime, LocalSystemTime) then begin
    Result := SystemTimeToDateTime(LocalSystemTime);
  end else begin
    Result := LocalDateTime;
  end;
end;

function SetFileTimesHelper(const FileName: string; DateTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  FileTime: TFileTime;
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  Result := False;
  Handle := CreateFile(PChar(FileName), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  try
    DateTime:=UTCDateTimeFromLocalDateTime(DateTime);
    DateTimeToSystemTime(DateTime, SystemTime);
    FileTime.dwLowDateTime := 0;
    FileTime.dwHighDateTime := 0;
    if SystemTimeToFileTime(SystemTime, FileTime) then
    begin
          Result := SetFileTime(Handle, nil, nil, @FileTime);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(Handle);
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.CreateDateFile(Dat : TDateTime);
var FileName : string;
begin
     FileName:=GetTempDir+FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd hhnnss', Dat)+'.txt';
     Memo1.Lines.Add(FileName);
     with TStringList.Create do
     begin
          text:='1';
          SaveToFile(FileName);
          Free;
     end;

     SetFileTimesHelper(FileName, Dat);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     CreateDateFile(StrToDateTime('23.02.2013 11:11:11'));
     CreateDateFile(StrToDateTime('06.05.2014 22:22:22'));      // file dated 23:22:22
end;
```

The first file is correctly dated, the 2nd is displayed in the windows explorer with 23:22:22.
What do I miss?

Comment: Explorer adjusts for DST probably. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/932955/how-to-handle-dates-and-times-that-include-dst), around middle of the article.

Comment: You can't assume the current timezone is the correct one for a date in the past since the time zone changes throughout the year for some locations - ex DST and EST. You need to either pass in a time zone or adjust the time passed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks brian for the comment.
Digging that way I found a solution:

```
GetTimeZoneInformation(tz);
SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(@tz, UTCSystemTime, LtSystemTime);
```

I didn't find the inverse function of SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime, but I used this function and then see the resulting offset. Then I invert the offset and the time is properly corrected.